# How to connect to a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have 2 views in my storyboard.
One is the defualt view connected to `ViewController`. I'll refer to it as `VC`.
The other view is one I created by dragging to the storyboard a `UITalbeViewController`. It's connected (through the custom class) to a new cocoa touch class, `MyTVC`. I'll call it `TVC`.
I connected a button on `VC` to `TVC` through a segue.

The problem is, now I have an array in `ViewController`, and I can't pass it to the `MyTVC` instance that populates the `TVC` view.

If I just create an instance of `MyTVC` in my `ViewController.m`, it's not connected to `TVC`. How could I access the `MyTVC` instance that's already connected to the `TVC` view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `VC` class, you need to implement the `prepareForSegue` method. That method can obtain a pointer to `TVC`, which you can use to pass information from `VC` to `TVC`.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ( [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowTable"] )
    {
        MyTVC *tvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        tvc.arrayForTable = self.arrayForTable;
    }
}
```

Note that the segue identifier is a string that you assign to the segue in the storyboard. You don't really need to check the segue identifier if you only have one segue.

Comment: Thank you so much! But maybe you want to wrap the if statement in brackets, and also change it to `MyTVC *tvc`?

Comment: Oops, you're right, I just typed it in here, should have typed it into Xcode first :)